# Find linked elements betwenn two list

Tags: python

Probably this is a very stupid mistake but I can't find a solution. I have the lists below:

```
node_pair = [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a')]
edge_list = [
    (1, 'unuseful thing', {'orig-id': 'a'}),
    (11, 'unuseful thing', {'orig-id': 'b'}),
]
```

I need to find the numeric couple in `edge_list` that is related to `node_pair`. For `('a', 'b')` I will see `(1, 11)` and for `('b', 'a')` I will see `(11, 1)`. Below my code:

```
for pair in node_pair:
    start_node = pair[0][0]
    end_node = pair[1][0]
    print(f'from {start_node} --> to {end_node}')

    graph_start_end_node = []
    for edge in edge_list:
        edge_orig_id = edge[2]['orig-id']

        if start_node == edge_orig_id:
            edge_start_node = edge[0]
            graph_start_end_node.append(edge_start_node)

        if end_node == edge_orig_id:
            edge_start_node = edge[0]
            graph_start_end_node.append(edge_start_node)

    print(graph_start_end_node)
```

The result is:

```
from a --> to b
[1, 11]
from b --> to a
[1, 11]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `append` works only when the order in the `node_pair` list is the same as in the `edge_list`, because this way the value is added at the end of the list. When the order could vary you have to place the matched value in a specific position - like:

```
graph_start_end_node = [None, None]
for edge in edge_list:
    edge_orig_id = edge[2]['orig-id']

    if start_node == edge_orig_id:
        edge_start_node = edge[0]
        graph_start_end_node[0] = edge_start_node

    if end_node == edge_orig_id:
        edge_start_node = edge[0]
        graph_start_end_node[1] = edge_start_node
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it hard to fix your code so I tried it this way.

```
node_pair = [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a')]
edge_list = [
    (1, 'unuseful thing', {'orig-id': 'a'}),
    (11, 'unuseful thing', {'orig-id': 'b'}),
]

for pair in node_pair:
    start_node, end_node = pair
    print(f'from {start_node} --> to {end_node}')
    graph_start_end_node = [e[0] for p in pair  for e in edge_list if e[2]['orig-id'] == p  ]

    print(graph_start_end_node)
```

Make a new list with a list iteration is generally easier than trying to append to an existing one.

Comment: The for statement and the following line could be combined into `for start_node, end_node in node_pair:`. So only two lines of code other than the initial conditions and the print statements.

Comment: Your code is more elegant then Iliya's but is less readeable for me that I've not strong skills as developer. Thank you anyway, your code is useful for me to understand "hard" code :)

Comment: No problem Massimiliano. I hope you have the opportunity to learn more. Python has a lot of depth.